# Опубликовал приложение в Google Play Market, но в поиске по точному названию найти не могу

Tags: java, android, google-play

в Play Console написано что приложение было опубликовано , загружено было 2 дня назад но в поиске по точному названию приложения я найти его не могу . Если ввожу инициалы разработчика то находит мое приложение и какое-то еще . В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Для вашей страны оно доступно?

Comment: как это проверить ?

Comment: В Play Console где же еще, если вы разработчик.

Comment: У меня более 2 дней поиск по названию не работал, это особенности поисковой системы. Ждите.

Comment: Скорее всего у вашего приложения много конкурентов и оно просто не попадает в поисковую выдачу.

Comment: Я загрузил приложение 15 января и до сих пор та же проблема. Пожалуйста, отпишитесь, если проблема решится

Comment: В поиске по названию может быть тысяча таких же приложений. И да системе нужно время на индексацию, особенно , если это блокнот итд. Хотя даже не особенно а просто нужно время. Попробуйте искать по имени пакета. Если находит из консоли, то , дцмаю все норм

Answer (score 1):

По-моему опыту приложение может не выдаваться по точному названию очень долгое время (месяцы), если оно не релевантно. Позаботьтесь о минимальной рекламе приложения, например в сервисе AdWords. Я рекламировал игру и всего за тысячу рублей получил около 2000 кликов по рекламе, 100 из которых привели к установке. Когда у приложения будет те самые 2000 просмотров и 100 установок, то оно точно будет выдаваться в поиске по точному названию на первой странице (а если название не типичное, то, возможно, и на первой позиции).

Кроме того, после такой рекламы (будем объективны, очень не дорогой рекламы) мое приложение по названию даже попало на первую страницу поисковой выдчи Google, правда, не в Play Market, а на ApkPure, но тоже неплохо, как по мне.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы о том что приложение не отображаются в Play Store то либо приложение не доступно в вашем регионе либо приложение закрытом стадии разработки либо де удален с маркета

Comment: оно отображается только если я ввожу инициалы разработчика, а если я ввожу название приложения в поиск то не находит просто

Comment: Ну все понятно. Он не доступен в вашем регионе

Comment: как это можно исправить , а то я уже все настройки открывал и не нашел

Comment: Можно через рут права изменить регион

Comment: Можно поподробнее для "особо умного" меня

Comment: Рут права это корневой доступ андроид телефона. Есть программаторы и ручной способ установки. Для удобство можно использовать программатор под названием Kingo Root. А потом установить программу Market Helper. Этот программа требует рут права. Вот так вот

Comment: Наздаровие. Изучайте Android, изучайте Java